# Is it possible to use the same ACM generated certificate with CloudFront and an ELB based in Ireland (eu-west-1)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

I used Amazon Certificate Manager (ACM) to generate a SSL certificate for my domain (ex. mydomain.com). In order to use this certificate in my Cloudfront CDN, the certificate was generated in N. Virginia.

My CDN is mapped to an ELB sitting in Ireland (eu-west-1).

The issue is that when I want to use the generated certificate in my ELB listeners, I'm not able to do it (I can't find the certificate).

am I just missing something? or is it impossible to do?

I tried to generate another certificate using ACM using the same region as the ELB and using the same domain. The certificate was issued with any problem and then I was able to attach it to the ELB. But as I expected it didn't work. I'm getting an error 502. Of course the ELB cann't offload the certificate sent by the CDN because it is based on another certificate.

Comment: I had a certificate from letsencrypt and it was working fine without any problem. Now I switched to Amazon ACM and I'm getting the error : NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID on chrome and when I proceed I'm getting 502 bad gateway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have 2 SSL certificates, just like how you have set them up, one in `us-east-1` for CloudFront and one in `eu-west-1` for the load balancer.

This is not an issue and should not cause any errors like the 502 error you are seeing. I'm not sure what you mean about the ELB "offloading" the certificate "sent" by the CDN. The load balancer should not care what certificate the CDN is serving, and the CDN shouldn't be sending that to the load balancer as part of the requests for origin data.

Comment: CloudFront does, however, require *either* (a) that the CN/SAN on the certificate on the ELB match the configured Origin Domain Name *or* (b) that the `Host` HTTP header be configured for whitelisting (in "Cache Behavior" settings) and the CN/SAN on the certificate on the ELB match the hostname appearing in the browser address bar.  A 502 results if neither of these conditions is met.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/http-502-bad-gateway.html#ssl-negotitation-failure

Comment: The issue is that I didn't generate a wildcard certificate.